# DateTime properties - list of Unspecified vs Local

Tags: c#, datetime

So `DateTime.Today` and DateTine.Now gives the time as `Kind==local` not  time as `Kind==Unspecified`

Is there a definitive list anywhere or a quick way to find out what kind DateTime.XXX will give you for any given property?

Comment: On my machine, both give `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DateTime.Now gives the time as Kind==unspecified

Where did you get that idea from?

It is unspecified if you don't specify it, e.g.

```
new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Kind // Unspecified
DateTime.MinValue.Kind // Unspecified
DateTime.MaxValue.Kind // Unspecified
```

If you specify the kind implicitly or explicitly, the Kind property will be set appropriately:

```
DateTime.Now.Kind // Local
DateTime.Today.Kind // Local
new DateTime(2000,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Local).Kind // Local

DateTime.UtcNow.Kind // Utc
DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Kind // Utc
new DateTime(2000,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc).Kind // Utc
```

Comment: Related reading that might interest you - [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).